# Mongo 3.0.2 driver: how to escape dots(.) in strings?

Tags: java, mongodb, escaping, special-characters, insertion

I want to put String "http://1.1.1.1/olala" into mongodb, but instead of

```
{data: "http://1.1.1.1/olala"}
```

I get

```
{data: {"http://1": {1: {1: "1/olala"}}}}
```

Is there a standard way to insert string with special characters into mongodb using java?

The way I'm doing the upsert is

```
collection.updateOne(new Document("name", key), 
                     new Document("$inc", new Document(methodName, 1)), 
                     opt.upsert(true), null);
```

where `methodName` is url with commas. I tried to quote values, but instead got

```
{data: {"'http://1": {1: {1: "1/olala'"}}}}
```

And beside that, I suggest that there would be more "bad" characters later.

UPD more complex example, but don't understand how it will help

```
final UpdateOptions opt = new UpdateOptions();
final String methodName = "http://1.1.1.1/ololo";
final MongoCollection<Document> collection =
    MongoAsyncClientFactory.getCollection();
//final String key = Statistics.getMainKey();
final String key = "any-key-you-want";
collection.updateOne(new Document("name", key),
                     new Document("$inc", new Document(methodName, 1)),
                     opt.upsert(true), null);
```

Comment: Which part of the code you've shown is the URL? It would really help if you could provide a short but complete example.

Answer (score 0):

**According to MongoDB** --> 
You are allowed to use use any (UTF8) character in the field name which aren't special (contains ".", or starts with "$")

and field `"http://1.1.1.1/olala"` contains `.` which is special character in MongoDB and refers to a subdocument, so it reads it as,

```
 {"http://1": 
    {1: 
       {1: 
          "1/olala" : someValue
       }
    }
 }
```

Refer to issue tracker https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3229

This issue has been addressed as **Works as Designed**, so I don't think that there will be any update regarding this.

**UPDATE**

I have just noticed that update code in the question doesnot actually seem to achieve `{data: "http://1.1.1.1/olala"}` or even `{name: "http://1.1.1.1/olala"}`

```
collection.updateOne(new Document("name", key), 
                     new Document("$inc", new Document(methodName, 1)), 
                     opt.upsert(true), null);
```

This actually creates document with a `{"name" : "test" }` for `key = "test"` and then updates the document to

```
{
  "http://1" : {"1" : { "1" : { "1/ololo" : 1 }
    }
  },
  "name" : "test"
}
```

So, if this is not something you are trying to achieve , consider changing your logic.

Comment: as I understand, solution is to manually escape `$` and `.`, or to avoid them at all?

Comment: You will have to avoid them Escaping `.` and `$` is not possible .You may try replacing them with some other combination of characters etc.

Comment: Also, I have just updated the answer. May be you need to check your update method too

Comment: But what if I _need_ to store special chars? Use \u escape instead? About update method - yes, It creates object with name `key` if it does not exist. It is logging, and name of `key` changes every day.

Comment: You cannot store `.` and keys starting with `$` in mongoDB ,directly ,by any means. Your application's data access layer can although create a mechanism that will encode and decode every such occurrences to some other group of characters

Comment: I understand. Just tried to find a way to do that with help of MongoDriver, and not DAO.